# Variation on finding Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

There is a famous recursive relation to find [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), i.e.

```
C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1)+(n-1)*C(n-1,k).
```

This is a solution to the following problem:

> Given a set of `N` distinct numbers, how many different permutations of the set exist such that there are exactly `K` left-to-right maxima?

This was not very hard, but the following little variation:

> Given a *multiset* of `N` numbers (not necessarily distinct), how many different permutations of the set exist such that there are exactly `K` left-to-right maxima?

Example:

Let the multiset be `S = {1,2,2,3}` [Note: the two `2`s should be considered non-identical while permuting] and `K = 3`. Then, the following permutations:

```
<1 2 2 3>
<1 2 2 3>
<1 2 3 2>
<1 2 3 2>
```

satisfy the required condition. Hence, the answer should be 4 (we do not need to find all the permutations but we are interested in the number of such permutations).

Note: An element should be considered a maximum if and only if all the elements occurring before it are strictly less than it. For example, in the above example `<1 2 2 3>`, the second `2` is not maximum but the first `2` is. Hence, this arrangement satisfy `K = 3` (not `K = 4`).

PS: I have worked a whole day to solve it, but can't do anything good. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck asking about this on http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: what is " left-to-right maxima"?

Comment: If in `<1 2 2 3>`, the second `2` is not maximum, how are you counting 3 left-to-right maxima? I count only two: 1 and 2.

Comment: @groovy while moving from left 1st maxima encountered is assumed to be the first number which is 1 in this case ,2nd maxima is 2 and third maxima is 3.

Comment: @SHB thanks...I assumed we had to stop if the condition was not met.